# Sumif date in weeknumber

Tags: date, google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I'm trying to sum the planned hours (right of the image), whenever that date has the same weeknumber.

**For example;**

If I have 2 dates in week 22 with 8 planned hours each, I want to see 16 planned hours in week 22.
It seems so simple, but I can't get it working.

```
=SUMIF(B3,ISOWEEKNUM(I5:I),J5:J)
```

Doesn't seem to work. I checked; `=ISOWEEKNUM(I5)` is giving me 22 as result.

Any ideas?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(J5:J; ISOWEEKNUM(I5:I)=B3))
```

Comment: It does do the trick, thanks! But if no results found, I get #N/A.

Comment: @Mr.Sam you can do: `=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(J5:J; ISOWEEKNUM(I5:I)=B3)))`